# Матрица. Помогите с ошибками в коде

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main()
{
int N,M,i,j;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    scanf("%d",&M);
int A[N][M];
int zero;
    zero=0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++ ) {
            A[i][j] =  rand()%(10);
            printf("%d ",A[i][j]);
            if (A[i][j]==0)
            zero=zero+1;
        }
    }
    printf("Zero:%d",zero);
    puts("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

В заданной матрице T (6,4) подсчитать количество нулевых элементов. Вывести исходную матрицу и количество нулевых элементов.
Программа не правильно работает

Comment: Ну а в чём заключается вопрос?

Comment: Нужно `A[i][j] == 0` вместо `A[i][j] = 0` в условии

Comment: И фигурную скобку передвинуть на пораньше

Comment: Отформатируйте код нормально

Comment: Ну так добавьте перевод строки после вывода каждой строки матрицы

Comment: @Sasha Добавьте `puts("\n");` между двумя `} }`

Comment: так трудно отформатировать код?

Comment: @CrazyElf `puts("\n");` сгенерирует два перевода строки

Comment: А, ну просто `puts("");` тогда. Уже не помню C почти.

Comment: Тогда уж лучше `putchar('\n');`